# Find intercept line and intercept point from data sets

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, physics

If I have two set of data such as:

```
   data5 = {{-2.`, -0.007008009734230887`}, {-1.5228787452803376`, 
        0.03830991145135324`}, {-1.`, 
        0.014605055663889335`}, {-0.5228787452803376`, \
    -0.01894062130202948`}, {-4.821637332766436`*^-17, \
    -0.008347638159826627`}, {0.4771212547196624`, \
    -0.014816432977226584`}, {1.`, 
        0.026906017564620632`}, {1.4771212547196624`, 
        0.3867839577138885`}, {2.`, 
        0.563485775448038`}, {2.4771212547196626`, 
        0.8415445741788008`}, {3.`, 
        1.0876231237435008`}, {3.477121254719662`, 
        1.377784291681077`}, {4.`, 2.021630688190699`}};
    
    data45 = {{-2.`, 0.028505019782043887`}, {-1.5228787452803376`, 
        0.145355594235398`}, {-1.`, 
        0.2367119881931513`}, {-0.5228787452803376`, 
        0.5038649822289214`}, {-4.821637332766436`*^-17, 
        0.8806044159680895`}, {0.4771212547196624`, 
        1.374633368524427`}, {1.`, 
        2.1552475532987945`}, {1.4771212547196624`, 
        2.790482121197644`}, {2.`, 
        3.3951653306812712`}, {2.4771212547196626`, 
        4.088759791862447`}, {3.`, 
        4.641978562314361`}, {3.477121254719662`, 
        5.262194040385147`}, {4.`, 5.247505774294609`}};
```

which plotted like:

```
ListPlot[data5, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Offset[13]}, AspectRatio -> 1 , 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13]]

ListPlot[data45, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Offset[13]}, AspectRatio -> 1 , 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13]]
```

Gives (without the red line):

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I find the "best intercept" of several points with the x-axis (as shown by the red line) for both data sets?. (I know there can be several intercepts but at least one that allow me to get the best fit from certain data that I can later extend or remove)
2. How can I find the x-axis value where the intercept happens?

Comment: Depending on how the data is generated and if you want to have an estimate as to how precise is the estimate of the y-estimate, you might consider piecewise linear regression:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192682/fitting-data-with-3-linear-fits/192686#192686.

Comment: @JimB thank you! that's a very good suggestion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fit5[x_] := Fit[data5, {1, x}, x]

Solve[fit5[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -0.628349}}
> ```

```
fit45[x_] := Fit[data45, {1, x}, x]

Solve[fit45[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -1.35754}}
> ```

```
Show[ListPlot[data5, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Offset[13]},
     Frame -> True,  AspectRatio -> 1, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13]], 
 Plot[Evaluate@fit5[x], {x, -2, 4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]]]]
```

[image]

Replace `data5` with  `data45` and `fit5` with `fit45` to get

[image]

Comment: kglr thank you very much!. I have one question: the fit to the first data doesn't seem very good, so 1) How can I make it better for instance by choosing what points to choose for the fit?

Comment: For example, for the first data set is it possible to select to use the first 7 data points (counting from high in the x-axis down)?

Comment: kglr, I solved it. I just need to put `data5[[-7 ;;]]`. I like your code. It's very flexible. Thanks. I am accepting your answer !

Answer (score 2):

"An estimate without an associated measure of precision is at best of unknown value."
-- *Me*

If your data generation process results in two connected line segments, you might consider piecewise linear regression.  Doing so will give you an estimate of precision of the value of the value of $x$ that results in a prediction of zero for the rightmost line segment.

If you have two connected line segments represented by $y = a_1+b_1 x$ for $x \leq c$ and $y = a_2+b_2 x$ otherwise, then to have them connect at $x=c$ you need

$$a_1+b_1 c=a_2+b_2 c$$

That means that $a_2$ is a function of the other parameters:

```
Solve[a1 + b1 c == a2 + b2 c, a2][[1]] // FullSimplify
{a2 -> a1 + (b1 - b2) c}
```

All of the parameters can be estimated using `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
f[x_, a1_, b1_, b2_, c_] := Piecewise[{{a1 + b1 x, x <= c}}, a1 + (b1 - b2) c + b2 x]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data5, f[x, a1, b1, b2, c], {a1, b1, b2, c}, x];
mle = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a1 -> 0.0034013, b1 -> -0.00193328, b2 -> 0.61858, c -> 1.04904} *)
Show[ListPlot[data5],
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data5[[All, 1]]], Max[data5[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

The estimated value of $x$ that results in $y=0$ for the rightmost segment is found with:

```
x0 = x /. Solve[a1 + (b1 - b2) c + b2 x == 0, x][[1]]
(* (-a1 - b1 c + b2 c)/b2 *)
```

That value for `data5` is

```
x0 /. mle
(* 1.04682 *)
```

An approximate 95% confidence interval for the "true" value can be found with the [Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

```
covMat = nlm["CovarianceMatrix"];
g = D[x0, {{a1, b1, b2, c}}] /. mle;
ci = {x0 - 1.96 Sqrt[g . covMat . g], x0 + 1.96 Sqrt[g . covMat . g]} /. mle
(* {0.763371, 1.33028} *)
```

So an approximate 95% confidence interval is (0.763, 1.330).  If that is too wide for what you need, you need more data or lower expectations.  The plot with the confidence interval looks like the following:

[image: Data, fit, and 95% confidence interval for x0 using data5]

Doing the same for `data45`:

[image: Data, fit, and 95% confidence interval for x0 using data45]